# TBB (Threading Building Blocks) on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, intel, tbb

Can someone point to me a quick way to get started working with TBB on Visual Studio 2008? I did go through this tutorial but it seemed kind of old ([LINK](http://drdobbs.com/212501909))

Comment: It _is_ old. Why do you want to use TBB instead of the Task class built into .NET 4.0?

Comment: Because my professor wants me to :-/

Comment: it amazes me how some schools stay in the past. At least this one is only three years in the past. Not like the schools still teaching .NET Remoting

Comment: @John: the referenced tutorial may be outdated, but TBB is not. So schools teachnig TBB don't stay in past, IMO. But I am a biased person :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the up-to-date documentation on TBB: http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/ver.php?fid=91; in particular, Getting Started and Tutorial documents should contain much of the info you are looking for.

Look at [TBB plug-in for Visual Studio](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/ver.php?fid=129); it automates tedious changes that you need to make in VS projects to configure paths and dependencies. It does not work with VS Express Editions however, due to limitations of those.

And in case of further assistance necessary, you are welcome at [the TBB forum](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-threading-building-blocks/).